# Scrapy server do not run spider

Tags: python, parsing, web-crawler, scrapy

I setup spider which perfectly runs from command line as

```
$ scrapy crawl somesite
```

And I made a shell script with this string and run it by cronjob. But it is very bad idea, because crawl not wait for ending previous scrapy crawler. So I've got some very nesty results. So I'm trying to run crawler through

```
$ scrapy server
$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2
```

And have no results. Crawler not run. I do not know how to schedule a spider run (for example every 10 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Scrapy are you using?

To solve the problem of wait for ending previous crawler try some simple control like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import traceback

spiderName='someSpider'

# Block file
pid = str(os.getpid())
pidfile = "/tmp/" + spiderName + ".pid"

if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
  print "%s is blocked, another process running..." % spiderName
  sys.exit()
else:
  file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)

try:
  os.chdir('/some/dir/crawlers')
  os.execl('/usr/local/bin/scrapy', 'foo', 'crawl', spiderName)
except OSError:
  print str(traceback.format_exc()) 

os.unlink(pidfile)
```